# Smarty Template PHP Script and Cascade

Tags: php, smarty, cascade

I need help. Not sure if anyone has used Cascade CMS but I am using one now and trying to call and display the contents from publicAccess.php. So I created a page (details.php) in Cascade and inserted this code under the HTML editor.

```
<span><br /> </span><!--#passthrough
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['ATS_CORE_PHP_LIB_PATH'].'/web/store/shopping/publicAccess.php';
?>
#passthrough-->
```

But nothing is happening!  No errors and just blank page when I try to access the details.php on my browser.  FYI, in the publicAccess.php file it has some php functions that calls different .tpl (smarty templates) files and inside those .tpl files there are some Bootstrap codes to display tables.  So my question is, what else do I have to do in Cascade in order to call this publicAccess.php file to display the contents in my detail.php page??

Thanks for your help in advance.

J

Answer (score 0):

The passthrough code works but it was a bug in the .php that prevented my page to show correctly. case closed.